# how to exclude element form array sum in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

i have this array:

```
[Jessica CS] => Array
    (
        [2011-04-20] => Array
            (
                [0] => 69.90
                [cancel] => 1311145200
                [1] => 29.95
                [2] => 69.90
            )
    )

[Rex CS] => Array
    (
        [2011-04-20] => Array
            (
                [0] => 119.94
                [cancel] => 
            )

        [2011-04-26] => Array
            (
                [0] => 199.50
                [cancel] => 
                [1] => 29.95
            )
....
```

and i am adding together these values by using a loop:

```
$i=0;
foreach($dates as $d){
$total[$i] += array_sum($value[$d]);
#i++;
}
```

this will add everything together and what i want is to exclude the `[cancel]` field from being added to the `array_sum`

edit: i could probably add the values that are `int`, but not sure how to sort them

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would change the layout of the array so that it went more like:

```
[Jessica CS] => Array
    (
        [2011-04-20] => Array
            (
                [cancel] => 1311145200
                [costs] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 69.90
                        [1] => 29.95
                        [2] => 69.90
                    )
                )
    )
```

Replacing [costs] with whatever name is most relevant.

**Working with your existing array**
Failing that

```
$i=0;
foreach($dates as $d){
    $total[$i] += array_sum(array_diff_key($value[$d], array('cancel'));
    #i++;
}
```

Comment: i understand, but i am stuck with it the way it is

Comment: it doesn't work, but i see where are you going with this, ill research more in this direction also

Comment: i ended up using `unset`. thanks you point me in the right direction

Comment: Note: The above code will not remove the index `cancel`. Looks like your doing `array_diff_key()` and removing the index `0`. This should be `$total[$i] += array_sum(array_diff_key($value[$d], array_fill_keys(['cancel', ...]));`

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array, perhaps like this:

```
$input = array(
    'Jessica CS' => array(
        '2011-04-20' => array(
            0 => 69.9,
            'cancel' => 1311145200,
            1 => 29.95,
            2 => 69.90,
        ),
    ),
    'Rex CS' => array(
        '2011-04-20' => array(
            0 => 119.94,
            'cancel' => null,
        ),
        '2011-04-26' => array(
            0 => 199.50,
            'cancel' => null,
            1 => 29.95,
        )
    )
);

$totals = array();

foreach($input as $person => $dates){
    $totals[$person] = 0;
    foreach ($dates as $date => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
            if ($key !== 'cancel') {
                $totals[$person] += $val;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($totals)
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [Jessica CS] => 169.75
    [Rex CS] => 349.39
)
```